# Under which conditions the solution to a linear system of ODE has a limit?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider a system of the form;

$$\mathbf{x}'(t)=A(t)\mathbf{x}(t)+\mathbf{f}(t),$$
$$\mathbf{x}(0)=\mathbf{b},$$

where $$\mathbf{x}(t)=(x_1(t),\ldots,x_n(t)),$$ $$\mathbf{f}(t)=(f_1(t),\ldots,f_n(t)),$$ $$A(t)=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}a_{11}(t)&\cdots&a_{1n}(t)\\ \vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\ a_{n1}(t)&\cdots&a_{nn}(t)\end{array}\right),$$ $$\mathbf{b}=(b_1,\ldots,b_n).$$

Let $\mathbf{x}(t)$ be a solution to this system. Under which (sufficient or necessary) conditions can we ensure the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\mathbf{x}(t)$ exist? Particular answers are welcome.

In the particular case I'm working on I know that $A(t)$ and $f(t)$ have finite limits, all entries of $A(t)$ are positive except for the diagonal entries which are negative. Also $A(t)$ is diagonally dominant by columns. If the question seems too general, you can assume that the matrices $A(t)$ ($t\geq0$) are simultaneously diagonalizable and that for all $t$, the first eigenvalue of $A(t)$ is real and is greater than the real part of any other eigenvalue.